# Python3 - How to convert a string to hex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string to hex character by character, but I cant figure it out in Python3.

In older python versions, what I have below works:

```
test = "This is a test"
for c in range(0, len(test) ):
   print( "0x%s"%string_value[i].encode("hex") )
```

But with python3 I am getting the following error:

LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs.

Can anyone help to tell me what the conversion would be in python3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

In python 3x Use [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/binascii.html) instead of hex:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'< character / string>')
```

Answer (score 4):

To print:

```
for c in test:
    print(hex(ord(c)))
```

To convert:

```
output = ''.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in test)
```

or without the '0x' in output:

```
output = ''.join(hex(ord(c))[2:] for c in test)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> test = "This is a test"    
>>> for c in range(0, len(test) ):
...     print( "0x%x"%ord(test[c]))
... 
0x54
0x68
0x69
0x73
0x20
0x69
0x73
0x20
0x61
0x20
0x74
0x65
0x73
0x74
```