# Python transform ascii hex to actual hex

Tags: python, encode

How to transform this unicode hex string ?

```
u'\x95\x93\xdfn\xe3D\x18\xc5q\xebv\xb3\xb4\xbb\x80\xb4H+\x84P\x05W,$\xfe......'
```

To real this hex

```
'\x95\x93\xdf\x6e\xe3\x44\x18\xc5\x71\xeb...'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 - How to convert a string to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909543/python3-how-to-convert-a-string-to-hex) (see the answer from acw1668)

Comment: Have a look at this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088375/how-do-i-convert-a-single-character-into-its-hex-ascii-value-in-python) it might be able to give an idea

Comment: The unicode hex string isn't a string, but it contains hex values

Comment: "hex" is is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean *"a string that completely consists of `\x` escape codes"*? Can you also explain in one sentence what you are planning to use this for - partly because I don't know what this would be good for, but if nothing else then because people who are trying to do this same thing can find this thread more easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
s = u'\x95\x93\xdfn\xe3D\x18\xc5q\xebv\xb3\xb4\xbb\x80\xb4H+\x84P\x05W,$'
s.encode('latin')

# b'\x95\x93\xdfn\xe3D\x18\xc5q\xebv\xb3\xb4\xbb\x80\xb4H+\x84P\x05W,$'
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm not too deep into unicode, but afaik this is the same. The point here was to use the proper encoding, which in this case is `Latin_1` (and e.g. _not_ `utf-8`, `cp1250`, `ascii`or whatever). And these encodings have several aliases, so `latin` works as well, and so does `latin-1`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb You're welcome - I learned it also today; see e.g. here: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html